# Why doesn't this JavaScript object key match a string with the same name?

Tags: javascript, object, key

Here is a basic comparison of a test object.

```
var testObj = {"hey":"blue"};
alert(Object.keys(testObj)); // alerts hey
if (Object.keys(testObj) === "hey") {
  alert('matches');
}
```

The first alert produces "hey", which matches the right side of the if statement comparison "hey" yet the alert('matches') does not fire, why is that?

edit: sorry dumb question

Comment: What `Object.keys` return? String/Array?

Comment: Use `Object.keys(testObj)[0] === 'hey'`

Comment: Not sure I understand, should I use console.debug or something to find out the type?

Comment: Oh it's possible to have more than one? Alright, even so, I need that as I have a for loop doing a check just like that actually with the 0 but it's an i (dynamic)

Comment: BTW, if you've used `==` to compare, it'd have worked.

Comment: @Tushar when should you not use the triple-equals comparison?

Comment: [Which equals operator (== vs ===) should be used in JavaScript comparisons?](//stackoverflow.com/q/359494)

Comment: @Tushar thanks for the link

Comment: Always read documentation regarding the function you're using. Also, a bit of `console.log` wouldn't hurt. Type-sensitive comparison is always a good thing.

Comment: @Vic console.debug still works right? I use it a lot and recently I noticed it being empty when I use it reverting console.debug in particular when returning JSON stuff from an AJAX call. Switching it back to console.log works though that's why I'm wondering why it seems to have stopped working, probably not true/mistake on my part.

Comment: @JacobDavidCunningham Read the documentation on `Console`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console It's apparently an alias to `.log()` but some browsers use it as another way to organize your logs from `.log`, `.warn`, `.error`.

Comment: Why the downvotes? How is this a bad question? Jacob didn't know how to debug properly and expected to be misunderstanding something. He cooked up a minimal test-case that **gave enough information for FIVE people to give an answer**. Yet, when I opened this question, there were 2 downvotes. I seriously don't get you people...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"**Object.keys(testObj)**" return an array. so basically you comparing an array.
try below code snippet

```js
var testObj = {"hey":"blue"};
alert(Object.keys(testObj)); // alerts hey
console.log(Object.keys(testObj));
if (Object.keys(testObj)[0] === "hey") {
  alert('matches');
}
```

Comment: I will admit my mistake first hand not providing full code. I followed the same structure as you've shown, but when I have a direct match, it does not work. Let me update my question with a copy of my code with switched values.

Comment: Sure. I'll try to help you.

Comment: Nope that was it, it's odd you have to specify even if there is only one value in there.

Answer (score 1):

`Object.keys()` method returns an array of a given object's own enumerable properties.So you need to get the `index` from that array

```js
var testObj = {
  "hey": "blue"
};
alert(Object.keys(testObj)); // alerts hey
//[0] will be first element in the array
if (Object.keys(testObj)[0] === "hey") {
  alert('matches');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[`Object.keys(testObj)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) is return  array not a string .see the `console.log`.`hey` is the first array first arguments.so you could match like this `Object.keys(testObj)` they will show the `hey`

```js
var testObj = {
  "hey": "blue"
};
console.log(Object.keys(testObj)); // alerts hey
if (Object.keys(testObj)[0] === "hey") {
console.log('matches');
}
```

Alert print the array as a string .see the both `alert` and `console.log`

```js
var array=['hi',' i am', 'array'];

console.log(array)
alert(array)
```

Answer (score 1):

You must need to specify index number in order to use it: check this.

```html
<script>
function myfn()
{
    var testObj = {"hey":"blue"};
    alert(Object.keys(testObj)); // alerts hey
    if (Object.keys(testObj)[0] === "hey") {
      alert('matches');
    }
}
</script>


<body onload="myfn();"></body>
```

Answer (score 1):

`Object.keys(obj)` retuns an array, so if you have multiple keys in the object then you can loop over them to match

```js
var testObj = {"hey":"blue", "something": "else"};
console.log(Object.keys(testObj)); // alerts hey
Object.keys(testObj).forEach(function(key) {
   if (key === "hey") {
    alert('matches');
  }
})
```

Also if you just wanna check whether a key is present in the obejct use `hasOwnProperty`

```
testObj.hasOwnProperty('hey')
```